# Codeigniter Get Image from dropzone

Tags: image, codeigniter, upload

I can't retrieve my image to update a user's profile. My upload image is successful. It can be seen in '/uploads' folder and in database. How to show it on profile page? I also have a default picture how to replace it?

> Memberlogincontroller

```
//The link to my upload page
    public function editphoto($id){
    $data = array(  
    "actionupdate"=>base_url('/index.php/Memberlogincontroller/updatephoto/'.$id),       
    "data" => $this->db->get_where('member',array('id'=>$id))   
    );    

    $this->load->view('member/upload', $data);
}

   public function getMember($id)
    {
    if ( (int)$id < 1)//$id is not an integer
    {
    redirect('Memberlogincontroller/member_view', 'refresh');//no valid uri segment
    }
    else
    {
    $this->load->model('Memberloginmodel');
    $memberinfo['memberinfo'] = $this->Memberloginmodel->getMember($id);

    if ( !$memberinfo['memberinfo'])//returned FALSE from model
    {
        redirect('Memberlogincontroller/member_view', 'refresh');//no $id in DB
    }
    else
    {
        $this->load->view('member/userprofile',$memberinfo);
    }
    }
    }

  //from Dropzone
   public function updatephoto($id){
   if ( (int)$id < 1)//$id is not an integer
{
    redirect('Memberlogincontroller/member_view', 'refresh');
}
   else
{
    $this->load->library('form_validation');//it's good to autoload it

    if (empty($_FILES['file']['name']))
    {
     $this->form_validation->set_rules('image', 'Image', 'required');
    }
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
        $this->load->view('member/userprofile');
    }
    else{
    if (!empty($_FILES)) {
    $tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $image = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $targetPath = getcwd() . '/uploads/';
    $targetFile = $targetPath . $image ;
    move_uploaded_file($tempFile, $targetFile);
    $data = array(
            'image' => '/uploads/'.$image,
        );

    $this->db->update('member',$data,array('id'=>$id));          
    $this->session->set_userdata($data); //i used this when i get to update other but in image i cant
    redirect('index.php/Memberlogincontroller/getMember/'.$id, 'refresh');      
    }
 }
 }
 }
```

Memberloginmodel

```
public function getMember($id)
{
$this->db->where('id', $id);
$query = $this->db->get('member');

if ($query->num_rows() !== 1)
{
    return FALSE;
}
return $query->row();//just single member data
}
```

> Upload page

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Upload Photo</title>
<?php include 'header_member.php'; ?>
 <link href="assets/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/css/dropzone.css"  type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/dropzone.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/dropzone.min.js"></script>
</head>
<script>
Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {

// Prevents Dropzone from uploading dropped files immediately
 autoProcessQueue: false,

  init: function() {
  var submitButton = document.querySelector("#submit-all")
     myDropzone = this; // closure

  submitButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  myDropzone.processQueue(); // Tell Dropzone to process all queued files.
  });

   // You might want to show the submit button only when 
   // files are dropped here:
   this.on("addedfile", function() {
   // Show submit button here and/or inform user to click it.
   });

  }
};
</script>
<body>

<div class="container">
<br>
<center><h3 class="description">UPLOAD PROFILE PICTURE</h3></center>
<br>
</div>

 <form action="<?php echo $actionupdate;?>" name="image" value="<?php echo     $this->session->userdata('image'); ?>" class="dropzone" enctype="multipart/form- data" id="my-dropzone">
 <input type="submit" value="update">

</form> 
</body>
</html>
```

> UserProfile Page (VIEW)

```
    <a href="#"><img height="200px" width="200px" src="<php echo base_url();?>uploads/no-avatar.jpg"></a>

 (How to replace this default avatar to an updated one?)

 below wont work
 <a href="#"><img height="200px" width="200px"src="<?php echo $this->session->userdata('image'); ?>"> --> done changing to base_url()
```

> Upload View

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Upload Photo</title>
    <?php include 'header_member.php'; ?>
     <link href="assets/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/css/dropzone.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/dropzone.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/dropzone.min.js"></script>
</head>
<script>
Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {
// Prevents Dropzone from uploading dropped files immediately
autoProcessQueue: false,
acceptedFiles: ".png,.jpg,.gif,.bmp,.jpeg",
maxFilesize: 1,
parallelUploads: 10,
addRemoveLinks: true,
init: function() {
var submitButton = document.querySelector("#submit-all")
myDropzone = this; // closure

submitButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  myDropzone.processQueue(); 
// autoProcessQueue: true// Tell Dropzone to process all queued files.
});

// You might want to show the submit button only when 
// files are dropped here:
this.on("addedfile", function() {
  // Show submit button here and/or inform user to click it.
});
}};

</script>
<body>

<div class="container">
<br>
<center><h3 class="description">UPLOAD PROFILE PICTURE</h3></center>
<br>
</div>

<!--<form action="<php echo site_url('/dropzone/upload'); ?>" class="dropzone"  >-->

<form action="<?php echo $actionupdate;?>"method="POST" id="my-dropzone" class="dropzone" name="image" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
<input type="hidden" name="hidden" value="<?php echo   $this->session->userdata('id'); ?>"/>
<button id="submit-all" type="submit" value="update">Submit</button>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Note: Your controller class name should be some thing like `Memberlogincontroller` only first letter upper case. Same with the file name. And same goes for models as well.

Comment: try with <?php echo base_url().$this->session->userdata('image'); ?>

Comment: thanks but i can only update a profile picture once. when i logged out the photo is gone. i added my upload view above